# Display time passed since most recent database DateTime and increment every second passed

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a database that stores the DateTime at which time a new book was entered into the system. In Xamarin.Forms, I wish to display the time difference in HH:MM:SS since the most recent DateTime in the database.

Currently, a label displays the time difference (HH:MM:SS:MS) but does not increment. The time difference displayed should increase by one second for each second that there is no new book entered.

I was thinking of using a loop to call the `CalculateTimeDifference()` function every second, but I was wondering if there might be a more efficient solution.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
       <Label x:Name="labelTimeSince" Text="00:00:00" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
       <Button Text="Add New" x:Name="BtnAdd" Clicked="BtnAdd_Clicked"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

MainPage.cs:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
     base.OnAppearing();
     CalculateTimeDifference();
}

void BtnAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Book book = new Book 
      {
          BookSaveTime = DateTime.Now
      };
      App.Database.SaveBook(book);

      CalculateTimeDifference();
}

void CalculateTimeDifference()
{
       var latestBook = App.Database.GetRecentBookDate().FirstOrDefault();
       var timeDifference = DateTime.Now - latestBook.BookSaveTime;
       this.labelTimeSince.Text = timeDifference.ToString();
}
```

Database.cs:

```
public int SaveBook(Book book)
{
      return database.Insert(book);
}

public List<Book> GetRecentBookDate()
{
      return database.Query<Book>("SELECT * FROM Book ORDER BY BookSaveTime DESC LIMIT 1;");
}
```

Book.cs:

```
public class Book: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    private DateTime bookSaveTime;
    public DateTime BookSaveTime
    {
        get
        {
            return bookSaveTime;
        }
        set
        {
            if (bookSaveTime != value)
            {
                bookSaveTime= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BookSaveTime");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do the following:

1. Format how the time difference in displayed (HH:MM:SS - with no milliseconds).
2. Continually increment the time difference by one second every second while no new Book is stored

Comment: Is your app single- or multi-user?

Comment: @Miamy It is single user.

Comment: use System.Timers.Timer, not a continual loop.  Fire the timer every second and update your UI.  Formatting datetime strings in C# is extensively docmented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Device.StartTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer?view=xamarin-forms):

MainPage.cs:

```
private Book latestBook;

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
     base.OnAppearing();
     latestBook = App.Database.GetRecentBookDate().FirstOrDefault(); 
     Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () => 
     {
         // BeginInvokeOnMainThread is needed because CalculateTimeDifference deals 
         // with user interface, which is allowed from main thread only
         Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => CalculateTimeDifference()); 
         return true; // let the timer continue work
     });
}

void BtnAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Book book = new Book 
      {
          BookSaveTime = DateTime.Now
      };
      App.Database.SaveBook(book);
      latestBook = book; // because the app is single-user, we don't need to ask 
      // the database every time, just to store the book we added will be enough
}

void CalculateTimeDifference()
{
       if (latestBook == null) // no books were stored before
       {
          this.labelTimeSince.Text = "-";
       }
       else
       {
          var timeDifference = DateTime.Now - latestBook.BookSaveTime;
          this.labelTimeSince.Text = timeDifference.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
       }
}
```